# How can there be prophets in jannah and a lot of woman in jahannam before the day of judgement?

Tags: jannah, day-of-judgement, miraj

As far as I am concerned, Prophet Muhammad(sm) saw many prophets in different stages of jannah during Miraj. Besides, I also came to know, that Muhammad(sm) also told that he saw people in jahannam and most of them were woman. Now,how can there be prophets in jannah and a lot of woman in jahannam before the day of judgement?

Answer (score 1):

A small correction to your question, the Prophet (PBUH) didn't see both the other Prophets or the women in either the Heaven (Jannah الجنة) or the hellfire (Jahannam النار او جهنم). He actually saw them in the different stages of the heavens (i.e.: skys, السماوات

Please refer to the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isra_and_Mi%27raj